# Defining and animating clamp movement

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

[image: Clamp][image: Clamp]

I want to animate these clamps through blender to move and open and close them.

The pins on them are actually in CAD programs when I define them with concentric constraint, but I don't know what kind of definitions I make here, I don't know how these parts will move.

Comment: Personally, I can't tell from the pic how this is supposed to operate.  Do you have any pictures of the device in another configuration?